# Proxy-authorization iphone

Tags: iphone, proxy

Is it possible to force iPhone to send login/password (Proxy-authorization:) in every request sent by my iPhone (of any apps)?
If that possible, please let me know I need document to start or source code.

Thank you

Comment: Please do use capital letters, this is just plain sloppy.

Comment: @dngfng noted.
Please i need help.

Comment: I think you can specify this in your iPhone Settings under general tab.

Comment: @iCreative: That's not possible for connection over 3G network

Comment: Yes. That can work only in case of Wifi, and also you cant force all applications in device to follow proxy of your specified..